# NPE for the case object before insert

Tags: apex, null-pointer

I am trying to write a method that goes through and creates the proper local timezone on the case object versus dates that could be done via the user since we might have different time zones for them vs clients. While doing this I am getting an NPE and am very confused as to why "cse.Created_Date_Local__c = System.Now().format('MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm a', caseIdTimezoneMap.get(cse.Id));" would cause an NPE.

```
public static void setCaseCreatedDateLocalTime(Case[] newCase, Map<Id, Case> newCaseMap) {

    Map<Id, String> caseIdTimezoneMap = new Map<Id, String> ();
    Map<String, CC_Area_to_Process__c> timezoneSidKey = new Map<String, CC_Area_to_Process__c> ();
    timezoneSidKey = CC_Area_to_Process__c.getAll();
    Set<Id> lotIdSet = new Set<Id> ();

    for (Case cse : newCase) {
        lotIdSet.add(cse.Lot__c);
    }

    Map<String, Lot__c> lotMap = new Map<String, Lot__c> ([SELECT Id, Community__c, Area__c FROM Lot__c WHERE Id IN :lotIdSet]);

    for (Case cse : newCase) {
        for (CC_Area_to_Process__c atp : timezoneSidKey.values()) {
            if (atp.Name == lotMap.get(cse.Lot__c).Area__c) {
                caseIdTimezoneMap.put(cse.Id, atp.timezoneSidKey__c);
            }
        }
    }

    for (Case cse : newCase) {
            cse.Created_Date_Local__c = System.Now().format('MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm a', caseIdTimezoneMap.get(cse.Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably, **caseIdTimezoneMap** does not contain **cse.Id** key, check this, please.

Comment: Would that be something like if(caseIdTimezoneMap.ContainsKey(cse.Id)){?

Comment: Yes, you are right, NPE can be caused in format function in case that the second argument is NULL. Check it with .containsKey() and try again.

Comment: I tried the if(caseIdTimezoneMap.Contains(cse)){ format but I am getting an error. 

Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Contains(Case) from the type Map<Id,String>

It did save when I did the other way with .containskey() but I was still getting the NPE.

Comment: I was able to get that error gone but it started to show an error for line "if (atp.Name == lotMap.get(cse.Lot__c).Area__c) {" I guess I am confused how this would cause an NPE with it having an if statement on that line?

Comment: It's the same here, add ```if(lotMap.containsKey(cse.Lot__c))```, you are trying to get Area__c from null-value.

Answer (score 1):

If the timezone can be (legitimately) missing from the related data, I suggest you fall back on a default e.g. GMT:

```
for (Case cse : newCase) {

    DateTine now = System.now();
    String format = 'MM-dd-YYYY HH:mm a';

    // Default to GMT if timezone not known
    String timezone = caseIdTimezoneMap.get(cse.Id);
    String formatted = timezone != null
        ? now.format(format, timezone)
        : now.format(format);

    cse.Created_Date_Local__c = formatted;
}
```

or you could use `UserInfo.getTimeZone()` as the default.